# Pagefile in Windows 10 Guest Virtual Machine

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, pagefile

I have a Windows 10 machine (32GB RAM) running a Windows 10 Guest (10GB RAM) for my work. The guest is given a 80GB dynamic disk, and the underlying storage is an SSD. The OS itself is < 20GB.

The guest was writing on average 5-10 MB/s of data to the pagefile, the cause was narrowed down to be due to pagefile. It was consuming a lot of host CPU (~25-50% of a 4C8T) and quickly expanding the size of my dynamic disk, all on top of the age-old debate of whether putting pagefile on SSD would cause wearing. It is using half a write cycle each day on my 1 TB SSD according to Crucial's SSD tool.

In my work environment, a software is constantly reading large files, and Windows keeps trying to cache the files in memory, which in turn gets written to pagefile.

Are there general guidelines for configuring pagefile in a VM? That take into account:

- Minimizing rapid expansion of dynamic disk size
- CPU overhead in guest I/O
- SSD wear (kind of debunked, but then we are getting QLC SSD now)

A few solutions could be:

- Disable pagefile (solves the constant write, but OS crashes when memory use peaks)
- Disable disk read cache (stops the wearing but slows the OS a lot)
- Passthrough a physical partition / device (haven't tried)
- Place pagefile in a shared folder (still a lot of overhead reading from host)
- Buy a physical machine for work (solves the virtualization overhead, but Windows would still be caching my file reads)
- Use linux, where one can set swappiness to zero

Comment: It’s sort of pointless to configure a page file within a VM since virtually everything is handled in memory on the host operating system. What Hypervisor are you using?